# Get sibling in jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I want to detect a click of two elements:

```
1) class is called advancedTargeting
2) the sibling li of the li that has the `area` attribute.
```

for example for the second demand:

```
<li area style='display:block'>bla</li>
<li>123</li>
<li>356</li>
```

so I want to catch the clicking on the sibling li of the li area. in this example, I want to get the onclick on li that his text is: `123`.

```
<li area style='display:block'>bla</li>
<li>356</li>
```

(and in this example, clicking on li of 356)..

they should run the same function.

I think it should do something like:

```
$('.advancedTargeting, li[area]:next').live('click', function () {

});
```

Comment: As an aside, you should look at using HTML5's `data-` attributes, instead of coming up with your own. ref: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [siblings](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_previous_siblings.asp) selector, you need.

```
$('.advancedTargeting, li[area] ~ li').live('click', function () {

});
```

Comment: but this will let me clicking on the siblings of advancedTargeting class. doesn't it?

Comment: I got what is your problem, try to separate event bindings (see edited answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.advancedTargeting, li[area] + li').on('click', function (){
  var number = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the first sibling of `li` that has attribute `area` simply use [siblings selector](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) combined with `:first selector`:

```
$('.advancedTargeting li[area]').siblings().filter(":first")
```

To add click function:

```
$('.advancedTargeting li[area]').siblings().filter(':first').on('click',function(){
//code goes here...
})
```

***[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/67pC6/)***

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('li[area]').next().on('click', function (){
    // click handling here
});
```

Though it'd be better to use the, valid, html 5 `data-*` attributes rather than your invalid self-created attributes.

Incidentally, `live()` was deprecated (replaced by `on()`) in jQuery 1.7, and removed in jQuery 1.9; and in jQuery <= 1.7 `delegate()` is recommended, in the docs, as being more efficient/performant.

References:

- [`next()`](http://api.jQuery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jQuery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.advancedTargeting li[area]:next').live('click', function () {
...
});
```

**OR**

```
$('.advancedTargeting li[area]:next').click(function () {
...
});
```

Comment: There is no `:next` selector